# Eclipse buttons menu change color when is in the background

Tags: eclipse

I have eclipse Neon.3 Release(4.6.3) and Ubuntu 16.04 and I use Darkest Dark Theme. Is this normal?

[image: eclipse buttons menu]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is "Yes, it's normal" though not pretty. This issue happens with light based themes in GTK (like Ambiance) when the Eclipse window does not have focus.

Those colors come from GTK theme itself and you can see the same issue even without Darkest Dark, like just using the regular Eclipse's Dark theme. Anyway, that issue is known by Darkest Dark devs (I contribute to that project) but can't tell if it's possible to fix.

The easiest workaround is to apply a different GTK theme, like OSX-ARC-Darker or Adwaita. Example: https://gyazo.com/d1bedaf928ff878368e9c02f7a75db60